# Изменение стиля шрифта в TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть 3 кнопки: полужирный, курсив и подчеркивание. Нажимая на каждую из них, изменяется стиль текста. Хочется, чтобы было как в ворде: нажимая 1 раз - появлялся новый стиль, второй раз на эту же кнопку - исчезал. Вот и возникла проблема: как убрать, скажем, жирный шрифт, чтобы при этом все остальное осталось также?
Я так писал:

```
if (textBox.Font.Bold)
{
    textBox.Font = new Font(textBox.Font, textBox.Font.Style | FontStyle.Regular);
}
else
{
    textBox.Font = new Font(textBox.Font, textBox.Font.Style | FontStyle.Bold);
}
```

Я понимаю, что `FontStyle.Regular` - не подходит, но не знаю, как написать по-другому, поэтому скинул пока так. Т.е. конкретно в этой ситуации жирный шрифт добавляется нормально, но потом не убирается.

Comment: FontStyle.Normal

Comment: а почему не использовать XOR  для установки/удаления флага? тогда даже if не понадобится.

Comment: @rdorn, никогда ранее не работал с оператором ^. Сейчас почитал на msdn, но все равно не очень понял, как это написать

Comment: Просто поставьте `^ FontStyle.Bold` в первом выражении вместо  `| FontStyle.Regular`.

Comment: добавил ответ, если что-то осталось непонятным, спрашивайте. Вообще с операцией XOR лучше дружить, иногда она много времени экономит =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте поразрядную операцию `^` (XOR)  для установки и удаления нужных флагов в свойстве `Font.Style`.

```
textBox.Font = new Font(textBox.Font, textBox.Font.Style ^ FontStyle.Bold);
```

Почему это будет работать:

Допустим имеем набор флагов `A:10101010` и нам необходимо изменить значение 3 бита на противоположное. Тогда:

```
  A: 10101010     C: 10100010
xor             xor
  B: 00001000     B: 00001000
=               = 
  C: 10100010     A: 10101010
```

Таким образом эта операция позволяет инвертировать значение флага, не изменяя при этом значения остальных флагов.

Comment: Все, разобрался, спасибо